# Logging abstract-valued output ports

Tags: drake

I can't find an abstract-valued version of `SignalLogger`. I've been writing custom loggers for abstract-valued outputs, such as this one for `ContactResults`:

```py
class ContactResultsLogger(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, publish_period_seconds: float):
        super().__init__()
        self.DeclarePeriodicPublish(publish_period_seconds)
        self.contact_results_input_port = self.DeclareAbstractInputPort(
            'contact_results', AbstractValue.Make(ContactResults()))
        self.sample_times = []
        self.contact_results_list = []

    def DoPublish(self, context, event):
        super().DoPublish(context, event)
        self.sample_times.append(context.get_time())
        self.contact_results_list.append(
           copy.deepcopy(self.contact_results_input_port.Eval(context)))
```

This works, but having one for every type of abstract-valued output can be tedious. Is there a better way to log abstract-valued outputs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code where you say `AbstractValue.Make(ContactResults())`, instead you could say `AbstractValue.Make(model_value)`, where `model_value` is a new, required constructor argument to this class.

Then, rename the class to something like `AbstractValueLogger` and rename the `contact_results_list` to something like `values`, and now you have a reusable logger, `system = AbstractValueLogger(model_value=ContactResults())`.